# How many epochs did faster RCNN train on papers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I am now trying to train faster RCNN on COCO or VOCs.

But I'm having hard time to get a good result.

In the paper, how many epochs did they train for them?
I trained a few epochs and still loss is reducing slowly but I paused it because it takes too much time.

And, any preprocess they didn't mention on the paper?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Which papers are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry. the original one.

Comment: And I have no clue about epochs on COCO and VOCs for typical RCNNs

Comment: I guess this would be a better place to ask this question: https://github.com/rbgirshick/rcnn/issues

Answer (score 0):

On this [URL](https://towardsdatascience.com/r-cnn-fast-r-cnn-faster-r-cnn-yolo-object-detection-algorithms-36d53571365e) you can see 84 hours of training for RCNN. You can find more details on RCNN in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2524.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the URL. but Does training hours mean only One GPU?